# Deploying QGIS settings in an enterprise environment

Tags: qgis, gui, deployment, enterprise

Are there any recommendations to manage and deploy various settings in QGIS (GUI-settings like visible plugins/toolboxes etc., settings in options, print compositions ...) to hundreds of clients / users?

Automated software installation is done so far ([distributing QGIS via OPSI](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179573/distributing-qgis-via-opsi)), but this comes with a standard configuration of the gui, which has by far too many options for a normal user, who only wants to see and print spatial data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure is.

QGIS stores stuff in two places:

- {USERHOME}.qgis2
- Registry (Windows) | .config (Linux)

`.qgis2` is for all templates, plugins, python code, processing models, etc

However you can also use the `--configpath` and `--optionpath` command args to set the folder to store the `.qgis2` folder and settings.   The settings will be saved as a ini file.

The registry keys (or ini file) will store everything else config related.

Here are some options for how you could deploy the settings to user.

**The registry and .qgis2 route**

- Install QGIS like normal
- Tweak all the settings you need, e.g add connection strings, move toolbars, etc
- Export the registry keys
- Take a copy of the .qgis2 folder
- Deploy the registry file to the users on login and the .qgis2 folder

**Note** You might not want to override it after you have done it first go or else you will nuke all the users settings.

If you need to rollout just a small change in the interface e.g toolbar placement, simply export that key from the registry and import that for each user.

**The configpath and optionspath route**

This option lets you move the settings and plugin folder.  Here is an example:

`qgis --configpath C:\temp\qgis --optionspath C:\temp\qgis`

This will move everything QGIS has for settings and .qgis2 into C:\temp\qgis.  This is super handy for creating "profiles" for users as you can change the folder the settings are loaded from

As an example I have one folder for training which is clean and wiped on each restart, one for demos which has large fonts and toolbar icons, and my normal one. I also use this option when developing QGIS to avoid messing my normal QGIS settings when testing ideas.

For going this route simply:

- Start QGIS using those command args
- Setup QGIS how you wish as the default setup
- Copy folders
- Deploy to user along with a shortcut for QGIS pointing to the settings folder

**Note** The last step is important else the user will still have QGIS pointed to the registry for their settings and not you folder

**Some other tips**

You can set extra plugin loading paths using an environmental variable:

`QGIS_PLUGINPATH`

point this to a network path to share common plugins between users.

In the QGIS options you can also set extra composer template, and project template paths. Set these to a network location to share common templates between users with a single location for storage.