# Sharing setup details between QGIS users?

Tags: qgis, wms, windows, extensions, user-account

We have just started using QGIS on windows at my work and I am the application responsible. I want my users to have a predefined setup with a couple of extensions and some WMS servers as a starting point. (If they want to add something afterwards, that's fine with me)

How do I do this?

I would prefer not to send out a description with open this menu and do that.

Is it possible to distribute some qgis-project or some type of .ini or .reg file with this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you refer to this [Deploying QGIS settings in an enterprise environment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/186633/35779).

> QGIS stores stuff in two places:
>
> {USERHOME}.qgis2
>
> Registry (Windows) | .config (Linux)
>   .qgis2 is for all templates, plugins, python code, processing models, etc
>
> However you can also use the `--configpath` and `--optionpat`h command args to set
>    the folder to store the .qgis2 folder and settings. The settings will be saved
>    as a ini file.
>
> The registry keys (or ini file) will store everything else config related.

Comment: Thanks, I was googling for a while but "deploying" was a term I didn't think of.