# Automatically deploy QGIS on multiple PCs in a class

Tags: qgis, windows-10, deployment, administration

We have a large computer class and would like to be able to install QGIS on all PCs automatically.
So far I found [a way to automatically deploy QGIS user settings](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/186624/34438), but not QGIS itself.
Is there a way to do it? (for instance, using Group Policies ([example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/teams-install#use-group-policy-to-control-the-installation-of-microsoft-teams)), or in any other way)

Class Setting: Windows 10, Microsoft Active Directory enabled

Comment: Maybe install one PC with Osgeo4W installer, and copy the directory `C:\OSGeo4W64` on all others, after I think you just have to create a script to launch all `.bat` files in the `C:\OSGeo4W64\etc\postinstall` directory.

Comment: For users without admin - AWS is another route for deploying QGIS and scalable depending on class sizes. https://www.xyht.com/spatial-itgis/using-qgis-in-the-cloud/ (it will save you time on each PC)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Use an IT Asset Manager

I would advice to use a management tool, which would enable you to handle not only the installation of QGIS, but also all current and future deployment/update needs.

About fifteen years ago, I used a similar software to manage a number of windows PCs, but it seems it has not been developed for a while.

A tool like

[The Open Endpoint Manager](https://theopenem.com/features/)

[image]

would probably cover all your needs, including the deployment of a QGIS msi.

Alternatives:

- [GLPI](https://glpi-project.org/) open source
- [GoverLan](https://www.goverlan.com/tools/software-deployment) commercial, but complete
- [PDQ Deploy](https://www.pdq.com/pdq-deploy/) commercial, complete
- [ManageEngine](https://www.manageengine.com/products/applications_manager/) commercial, probably the reference for all competitors

Answer (score 0):

You found an answer for deploy user settings for QGIS Version 2. In Version 3 there are other possibilities. As far as I know, nothing is stored in the windwos registry anymore.
Working with user profiles is a good idea: [see doc](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/de/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#working-with-user-profiles)

Deploying QGIS itself on a large number computers should be possible by installing it on a shared network drive. Maybe you have to alter some pathes in some batch files (from "C:\osgeo4w64" to "\server\osgeo4w64" or "Q:" or something like that).